# CRON job cannot find environment variable set in docker-compose

Tags: docker, cron, docker-compose

I am setting some environment variables in `docker-compose` that are being used by a python application being run by a cron job.

**docker-compose.yaml:**

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  zookeeper:
    container_name: zookeeper
    image: zookeeper:3.3.6
    restart: always
    hostname: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOO_MY_ID: 1
  kafka:
    container_name: kafka
    image: wurstmeister/kafka:1.1.0
    hostname: kafka
    links:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "topic:1:1"
      KAFKA_LOG_MESSAGE_TIMESTAMP_TYPE: LogAppendTime
      KAFKA_MESSAGE_TIMESTAMP_TYPE: LogAppendTime
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
  data-collector:
    container_name: data-collector
    #image: mystreams:0.1
    build:
      context: /home/junaid/eMumba/CASB/Docker/data_collector/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    links:
      - kafka
    environment:
      - KAFKA_HOST=kafka
      - OFFICE_365_APP_ID=98aff1c5-7a69-46b7-899c-186851054b43
      - OFFICE_365_APP_SECRET=zVyS/V694ffWe99QpCvYqE1sqeqLo36uuvTL8gmZV0A=
      - OFFICE_365_APP_TENANT=2f6cb1a6-ecb8-4578-b680-bf84ded07ff4
      - KAFKA_CONTENT_URL_TOPIC=o365_activity_contenturl
      - KAFKA_STORAGE_DATA_TOPIC=o365_storage
      - KAFKA_PORT=9092
      - POSTGRES_DB_NAME=casb
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pakistan
      - POSTGRES_HOST=postgres_database
    depends_on:
      postgres_database:
        condition: service_healthy
  postgres_database:
    container_name : postgres_database
    build: 
      context: /home/junaid/eMumba/CASB/Docker/data_collector/
      dockerfile: postgres.dockerfile
    #image: ayeshaemumba/casb-postgres:v3
    #volumes:
    #  - ./postgres/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pakistan
      POSTGRES_DB: casb
    expose:
      - "5432"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 3
```

When I exec inside `data-collector` container and echo any of the environment variable I can see that its set:

```
># docker exec -it data-collector sh
># echo $KAFKA_HOST
> kafka
```

But my cron job logs shows `KeyError: 'KAFKA_HOST'`
It means my cron job cannot find environment variables.

Now I have two questions:

1) Why are environment variables not set for cron job?

2) I know that I can pass environment variables as a shell script and run it while building image. But is there a way to pass environment variables from docker-compose?

**Update:**

Cron job is defined in docker file for python application.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3.5-slim

# Creating Application Source Code Directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

# Setting Home Directory for containers
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Installing python dependencies
COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app/
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Copying src code to Container
COPY . /usr/src/app

# Add storage crontab file in the cron directory
ADD crontab-storage /etc/cron.d/storage-cron

# Give execution rights on the storage cron job
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/storage-cron

RUN chmod 0644 /usr/src/app/cron_storage_data.sh

# Create the log file to be able to run tail
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

#Install Cron
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install cron

# Run the command on container startup
CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

**crontab-storage:**

```
*/1 * * * * sh /usr/src/app/cron_storage_data.sh
# Don't remove the empty line at the end of this file. It is required to run the cron job
```

**cron_storage_data.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /usr/src/app
/usr/local/bin/python3.5 storage_data_collector.py
```

Comment: With respect to 1) Where is your cron job defined? If it is on the host then it won't be able to see environment variables inside the containers. 2) You can reference environment variables from the host using `${HOST_VARIABLE_NAME}` syntax inside the docker compose file e.g. `KAFKA_HOST=${KAFKA_HOST}`

Comment: I am defining cron job in dockerfile for the python application. I will update the question

Comment: What user is cron running as?

Comment: cron is running as root I guess

Comment: So root won't have access to the environment if your environment was set up under a different user. Try running `crontab -u <your-user> -e` to edit the user cron and set the job on there.

Comment: you also have to run cron with `-f` option so it doesn't run demonised, ie `cron -f`

Answer (score 4):

Cron doesn't inherit docker-compose environment variables by default. A potential workaround for this situation is to:

1.Pass the environment variables from docker-compose to a local .env file

```
touch .env
echo "export KAFKA_HOST=$KAFKA_HOST" > /usr/src/app/.env
```

2.`source` the `.env` file before the `cron` task execution

```
* * * * * <username> . /usr/src/app/.env && sh /usr/src/app/cron_storage_data.sh
```

This is how your update environment file will look like:

Before:

```
{'SHELL': '/bin/sh', 'PWD': '/root', 'LOGNAME': 'root', 'PATH': '/usr/bin:/bin', 'HOME': '/root'}
```

After:

```
{'SHELL': '/bin/sh', 'PWD': '/root', 'KAFKA_HOST': 'kafka', 'LOGNAME': 'root', 'PATH': '/usr/bin:/bin', 'HOME': '/root'}
```